# Switch Workspace can't be saved

Tags: java, rcp, emf

Im switching to another workspace on my Application Workbench, everything works(restart -> newWorkspace) fine but the moment i restart the app myself the newWorkspace is no more and the previous workspace is chosen. 
Is there maybe an action missing from the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor, or is it that the defaultworkspace is always chosen after a startup (except the one following the workspace switch)?
Can somone please point me to the right direction to correct this behaviour.

I tried to work around it by choosing under Preferences->general->workspaces prompt on startup but it just gets ignored.

[MissingFilesJRE202](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXBn4.png) This Picture is a Windiff screen capture elustrating the files that don't exist after upgrading from jre1.8.0.131 to jre1.8.0.202 and Oracle JRE to OpenJRE. Which means chances are high that the configuration of plugin ini have changed causing this issue.

No Error can be seen in the log file.Thank you.
Best regards

Comment: The code in the `IApplication` selects the workspace, see `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication` for example

Comment: Very helpfull, thanks

Comment: Since i am using the same things as here : https://github.com/buchen/bundled-jre. I think the upgrade from jre1.8.0.131 1.8.0.202 changed the jvm.dll. Because earlier versions of the app running v.1.8.0.131 start similar to eclipse IDE by asking to choose a workspace. So it is a startoption failure i assume

Comment: I found out that the file org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs in \configuration\.settings the Line SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=false was, so changed it to true and i get my Choise of workspace by start , but after choosing a valid workspace i get the Error in my metadata/.log: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Comment: java.version=1.8.0_222
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
Framework arguments:  -refresh
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clean -refresh

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-12-20 09:06:00.178
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (114).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:800)